# Julia CUDA: LoadError: GPU broadcast resulted in non-concrete element type Any

Tags: julia

I have to analyze some data using maximum likelihood methods, but CUDA doesn't like how I handle type instability. Any idea on how I could fix this?
I tried my best in forcing concrete return types by declaring the type of every function argument, but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: I moved back some function declarations inside where they belonged.
Here is an extract of the problematic part of the program:

```
function ln_likelihood( a_c::Float64,
                        a_p::Float64,
                        θ_1::Float64,
                        θ_2p::CuArray{Float64},
                        θ_2c::CuArray{Float64},
                        ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                        σ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                        ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64},
                        σ_c::CuArray{Float64})
    ...
    #return Float64
end

function trova_max_likelihood(  θ_1::Float64,
                                θ_2p::CuArray{Float64},
                                θ_2c::CuArray{Float64},
                                ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                                σ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                                ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64},
                                σ_c::CuArray{Float64})

    ...

    function funzione_likelirobin(a_c::Float64, a_p::Float64)
        global θ_1,θ_2p,θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c 
        ln_likelihood(a_c,a_p,θ_1,θ_2p,θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c)
    end

    funzione_likelihood(x::Tuple{Float64, Float64}) = funzione_likelirobin(x[1],x[2])

    @code_warntype funzione_likelihood.(range)
    #Where range::CuArray{Tuple{Float64,Float64}}
    ...
end


trova_max_likelihood(gθ_1, gθ_2p, gθ_2c, gϵ_p, gσ_p, gϵ_c, gσ_c)
```

And the output I get:

```
Variables
  #self#::Core.Const(var"##dotfunction#274#175"{var"#funzione_likelihood#174"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#173"}}(var"#funzione_likelihood#174"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#173"}(var"#funzione_likelirobin#173"())))
  x1::CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}

Body::Union{}
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :funzione_likelihood)::Core.Const(var"#funzione_likelihood#174"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#173"}(var"#funzione_likelirobin#173"()))
│   %2 = Base.broadcasted(%1, x1)::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{CUDA.CuArrayStyle{1}, Nothing, var"#funzione_likelihood#174"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#173"}, Tuple{CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}
│        Base.materialize(%2)
└──      Core.Const(:(return %3))
ERROR: LoadError: GPU broadcast resulted in non-concrete element type Any.
This probably means that the function you are broadcasting contains an error or type instability.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base .\error.jl:33
 [2] copy
   @ ~\.julia\packages\GPUArrays\gkF6S\src\host\broadcast.jl:44 [inlined]
 [3] materialize
   @ .\broadcast.jl:883 [inlined]
 [4] trova_max_likelihood(θ_1::Float64, θ_2p::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, θ_2c::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, σ_p::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64, 1, C, σ_c::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
   @ Main ~\Documents\GitHub\lab2\Lab2\Esercizio 5\esercizio5.jl:82
 [5] top-level scope
   @ ~\Documents\GitHub\lab2\Lab2\Esercizio 5\esercizio5.jl:99
 [6] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [7] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(identity), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1094
in expression starting at C:\Users\marce\Documents\GitHub\lab2\Lab2\Esercizio 5\esercizio5.jl:99
```

EDIT 2: I tried switching to regular arrays and the code above wouldn't work. I had to delete a line and define:

```
function funzione_likelirobin(a_c::Float64, a_p::Float64)
        ln_likelihood(a_c,a_p,θ_1,θ_2p,θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c)
end
```

So I made the same change in the code with `CuArray`s. The output I get is now:

```
Variables
  #self#::var"##dotfunction#260#56"{var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}}
  x1::CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}

Body::CuArray{_A, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer} where _A
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :funzione_likelihood)::var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}
│   %2 = Base.broadcasted(%1, x1)::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{CUDA.CuArrayStyle{1}, Nothing, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}, Tuple{CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}
│   %3 = Base.materialize(%2)::CuArray{_A, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer} where _A
└──      return %3
ERROR: LoadError: InvalidIRError: compiling kernel broadcast_kernel(CUDA.CuKernelContext, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Nothing, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}}}, Tuple{Base.Broadcast.Extruded{CuDeviceVector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1}, Tuple{Bool}, Tuple{Int64}}}}, Int64) resulted in invalid LLVM IR
Reason: unsupported dynamic function invocation (call to ln_likelihood)
Stacktrace:
 [1] funzione_likelirobin
   @ ~\Documents\GitHub\lab2\Lab2\Esercizio 5\esercizio5.jl:76
 [2] funzione_likelihood
   @ ~\Documents\GitHub\lab2\Lab2\Esercizio 5\esercizio5.jl:79
 [3] _broadcast_getindex_evalf
   @ .\broadcast.jl:648
 [4] _broadcast_getindex
   @ .\broadcast.jl:621
 [5] getindex
   @ .\broadcast.jl:575
 [6] broadcast_kernel
   @ ~\.julia\packages\GPUArrays\gkF6S\src\host\broadcast.jl:59
Stacktrace:
  [1] check_ir(job::GPUCompiler.CompilerJob{GPUCompiler.PTXCompilerTarget, CUDA.CUDACompilerParams, GPUCompiler.FunctionSpec{GPUArrays.var"#broadcast_kernel#17", Tuple{CUDA.CuKernelContext, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Nothing, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}}}, Tuple{Base.Broadcast.Extruded{CuDeviceVector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1}, Tuple{Bool}, Tuple{Int64}}}}, Int64}}}, args::LLVM.Module)
    @ GPUCompiler ~\.julia\packages\GPUCompiler\HeCT6\src\validation.jl:111
  [2] macro expansion
    @ ~\.julia\packages\GPUCompiler\HeCT6\src\driver.jl:326 [inlined]
  [3] macro expansion
    @ ~\.julia\packages\TimerOutputs\YJq3h\src\TimerOutput.jl:252 [inlined]
  [4] macro expansion
    @ ~\.julia\packages\GPUCompiler\HeCT6\src\driver.jl:324 [inlined]
  [5] emit_asm(job::GPUCompiler.CompilerJob, ir::LLVM.Module; strip::Bool, validate::Bool, format::LLVM.API.LLVMCodeGenFileType)
    @ GPUCompiler ~\.julia\packages\GPUCompiler\HeCT6\src\utils.jl:64
  [6] cufunction_compile(job::GPUCompiler.CompilerJob)
    @ CUDA ~\.julia\packages\CUDA\sCev8\src\compiler\execution.jl:326
  [7] cached_compilation(cache::Dict{UInt64, Any}, job::GPUCompiler.CompilerJob, compiler::typeof(CUDA.cufunction_compile), linker::typeof(CUDA.cufunction_link))
    @ GPUCompiler ~\.julia\packages\GPUCompiler\HeCT6\src\cache.jl:90
  [8] cufunction(f::GPUArrays.var"#broadcast_kernel#17", tt::Type{Tuple{CUDA.CuKernelContext, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Nothing, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}}}, Tuple{Base.Broadcast.Extruded{CuDeviceVector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1}, Tuple{Bool}, Tuple{Int64}}}}, Int64}}; name::Nothing, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ CUDA ~\.julia\packages\CUDA\sCev8\src\compiler\execution.jl:297
  [9] cufunction(f::GPUArrays.var"#broadcast_kernel#17", tt::Type{Tuple{CUDA.CuKernelContext, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Nothing, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}}}, Tuple{Base.Broadcast.Extruded{CuDeviceVector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1}, Tuple{Bool}, Tuple{Int64}}}}, Int64}})
    @ CUDA ~\.julia\packages\CUDA\sCev8\src\compiler\execution.jl:291
 [10] macro expansion
    @ ~\.julia\packages\CUDA\sCev8\src\compiler\execution.jl:102 [inlined]
 [11] launch_heuristic(::CUDA.CuArrayBackend, ::GPUArrays.var"#broadcast_kernel#17", ::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, ::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Nothing, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}, Tuple{Base.Broadcast.Extruded{CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Tuple{Bool}, Tuple{Int64}}}}, ::Int64; elements::Int64, elements_per_thread::Int64)
    @ CUDA ~\.julia\packages\CUDA\sCev8\src\gpuarrays.jl:17
 [12] copyto!(dest::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, bc::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Nothing, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, var"#funzione_likelihood#55"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#54"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}, Tuple{CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}})
    @ GPUArrays ~\.julia\packages\GPUArrays\gkF6S\src\host\broadcast.jl:65
in expression starting at C:\Users\marce\Documents\GitHub\lab2\Lab2\Esercizio 5\esercizio5.jl:100
```

Comment: It's not apparent to me where the type instability issues are, possibly due to your thorough annotations. What stands out is all the Union{}, which indicates those variables have no inferrable types at all, so whatever you run on the right hand side is failing to even return. It seems to start at your `likelihood = ...` line, so maybe you should `@code_warntype` that part. Looks like it may be rooted in your `funzione_likelirobin` using a bunch of global variables? Global variables are often type-unstable, but I'm not sure, I can't find where they're even defined.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Thank you for your comment! The global variables used by `likelirobin` are actually the parameters you feed into `trova_max_likelihood`.

Comment: I can't understand why this is causing problems, since those types are forced in `ln_likelihood`. Anyway, I'll try what you suggested and hopefully it will shed some light. P.S. What do you mean by "through notation"? Is it a polite invitation to better comment my code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a silly mistake: `likelirobin` was originally declared inside `trova_max_likelihood`, but I moved it outside to see if it solved the problem. Of course it doesn't, since there are no global variables named that way. Let me fix this and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided seems to be a bit short of an MWE. However, filling in some random data of the specified types, we have:

```
using CUDA
a_c, a_p, θ_1 = rand(3)
N = 1000
θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c = ntuple(x->CUDA.randn(Float64, N), 6)


function ln_likelihood( a_c::Float64,
                        a_p::Float64,
                        θ_1::Float64,
                        θ_2p::CuArray{Float64},
                        θ_2c::CuArray{Float64},
                        ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                        σ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                        ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64},
                        σ_c::CuArray{Float64})
    # ...
    return a_c + a_p + θ_1 + sum(θ_2p) + sum(θ_2c) + sum(ϵ_p) + sum(σ_p) + sum(ϵ_c) + sum(σ_c)
end


function trova_max_likelihood(  θ_1::Float64,
                                θ_2p::CuArray{Float64},
                                θ_2c::CuArray{Float64},
                                ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                                σ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                                ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64},
                                σ_c::CuArray{Float64})

    # ...

    function funzione_likelirobin(a_c::Float64, a_p::Float64)
        global θ_1, θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c
        ln_likelihood(a_c, a_p, θ_1, θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c)
    end

    funzione_likelihood(x::Tuple{Float64, Float64}) = funzione_likelirobin(x[1],x[2])

    # Better make a range if we want to broadcast over it
    range = CUDA.fill((1., 2.), 10)

    @code_warntype funzione_likelihood.(range)
    #Where range::CuArray{Tuple{Float64,Float64}}
end
```

which runs for me without any error, and gives blue, stably-inferred types in the `@code_warntype` output:

```
julia> trova_max_likelihood(θ_1, θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c)
MethodInstance for (::var"##dotfunction#413#25"{var"#funzione_likelihood#24"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"}})(::CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
  from (::var"##dotfunction#413#25")(x1) in Main
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(var"##dotfunction#413#25"{var"#funzione_likelihood#24"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"}}(var"#funzione_likelihood#24"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"}(var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"())))
  x1::CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}
Body::Union{}
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :funzione_likelihood)::Core.Const(var"#funzione_likelihood#24"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"}(var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"()))
│   %2 = Base.broadcasted(%1, x1)::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{CUDA.CuArrayStyle{1}, Nothing, var"#funzione_likelihood#24"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#23"}, Tuple{CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}
│        Base.materialize(%2)
└──      Core.Const(:(return %3))
```

So it would seem that the instability is likely coming from somewhere in the code you have elided with `...`.

That said, I would heavily recommend avoiding global variables; either just specifying the variables explicitly in the function signature, or if you have to, capturing local variables in a closure, would be preferable to using globals -- which can be a major source of type-instability.

Using a closure instead of globals as follows

```
using CUDA
a_c, a_p, θ_1 = rand(3)
N = 1000
θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c = ntuple(x->CUDA.randn(Float64, N), 6)


function ln_likelihood( a_c::Float64,
                        a_p::Float64,
                        θ_1::Float64,
                        θ_2p::CuArray{Float64},
                        θ_2c::CuArray{Float64},
                        ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                        σ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                        ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64},
                        σ_c::CuArray{Float64})
    # ...
    return a_c + a_p + θ_1 + sum(θ_2p) + sum(θ_2c) + sum(ϵ_p) + sum(σ_p) + sum(ϵ_c) + sum(σ_c)
end


function trova_max_likelihood(  θ_1::Float64,
                                θ_2p::CuArray{Float64},
                                θ_2c::CuArray{Float64},
                                ϵ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                                σ_p::CuArray{Float64},
                                ϵ_c::CuArray{Float64},
                                σ_c::CuArray{Float64})

    # ...

    function funzione_likelirobin(a_c::Float64, a_p::Float64)
        ln_likelihood(a_c, a_p, θ_1, θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c)
    end

    funzione_likelihood(x::Tuple{Float64, Float64}) = funzione_likelirobin(x[1],x[2])

    # Better make a range if we want to broadcast over it
    range = CUDA.fill((1., 2.), 10)

    @code_warntype funzione_likelihood.(range)
    #Where range::CuArray{Tuple{Float64,Float64}}
end
```

yields a slightly different `@code_warntype` output, but still with blue, stably-inferred types and no error

```
julia> trova_max_likelihood(θ_1, θ_2p, θ_2c, ϵ_p, σ_p, ϵ_c, σ_c)
MethodInstance for (::var"##dotfunction#414#30"{var"#funzione_likelihood#29"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#28"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}})(::CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
  from (::var"##dotfunction#414#30")(x1) in Main
Arguments
  #self#::var"##dotfunction#414#30"{var"#funzione_likelihood#29"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#28"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}}
  x1::CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}
Body::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(#self#, :funzione_likelihood)::var"#funzione_likelihood#29"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#28"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}
│   %2 = Base.broadcasted(%1, x1)::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{CUDA.CuArrayStyle{1}, Nothing, var"#funzione_likelihood#29"{var"#funzione_likelirobin#28"{Float64, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}, Tuple{CuArray{Tuple{Float64, Float64}, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}
│   %3 = Base.materialize(%2)::CuArray{Float64, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}
└──      return %3
```

Comment: What do you mean by MWE? 
Anyway, I posted the full code here: [link](https://github.com/marcellofonda/Lab2/blob/main/Esercizio%205/esercizio5_costanti_CUDA.jl). I wasn't sure if I should put it in the main post as well. Hope this helps in reproducing the error (I have worked on it a bit since posting the question, unfortunately in the opposite direction of what you suggest)
About the code you wrote: 
- there is no need to declare `a_c` and `a_p` since they only appear as parameters.
- Could you please highlight the difference between the two variants? Is it just the `global` statement?

Comment: MWE = minimal working example -- the simplest possible code code that can still just be directly copy-pasted and run as-is to reproduce a problem or error

Comment: Yes, just the `global`. If I can reproduce the error you get with the code you've just linked I'll add another answer though.